# I get this error 'User' object has no attribute 'get' in contact form

Tags: python, django

H
when i want to submit contact form when i push submit button 
i get error user object has no attribute 'get' 
i add else: in end of function else : contactform() but after that again 
i get this error i don't know what i have to do ? 
tnx for help .

**views.py**

```
def ContactUs(request):
    title = 'Contac Us'
    if request.method =="POST":
        form = ContactForm(request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            to_email = [email,"some other thing "]
            contact_message = (name,email)
            send_mail(subject,contact_message,message,from_email,to_email,fail_silently=True)
    else :
        form = ContactForm()
    context = {'title': title, 'form': form}
    return render(request,'contact_us.html',context)
```

**contact.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}
    Contact Us {{ block.super|title }}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            {{ title }}
            <form action="" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% for field in form %}
                <div class="form-group" >
                    {{ field.label_tag }}
                    {{ field.error }}
                    {{ field }}
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Forms.py

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    message = forms.TextInput()


    class Meta :
        model = ContactUs
        fields = ['name','email','subject']
```

Comment: Please provide the *full* traceback.

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem http://dpaste.com/3DMJ9MA full traceback .tnx again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the `request.POST` attribute to the form (or `request.GET` or another dictionary-like object that contains the data that should be passed to the form), instead of the user that logged in, so:

```
form = ContactForm(request.POST)
```

instead of:

```
form = ContactForm(request.user)
```